# Nested CollectionView Cell did not appear

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I nested collectionView inside collectionView Cell like this:
[image]

inside first collectionView Cell, I put this code :

```
class CaseCellView: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblHeader: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewItemList: UICollectionView!
    var sellingArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    override func awakeFromNib(){
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: collectionViewItemList.frame.width, height: collectionViewItemList.frame.width)
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0
        self.collectionViewItemList.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
        self.collectionViewItemList?.delegate = self
        self.collectionViewItemList?.dataSource = self
        self.collectionViewItemList.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.sellingArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionViewItemList.frame.width, height: collectionViewItemList.frame.width)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "caseListCell", for: indexPath)as! CaseListCellView
        cell1.lblItemList.text = self.sellingArray[indexPath.item]
        cell1.lblItemList.textColor = .white
        cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        return cell1

    }
}

class CaseListCellView: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblItemList: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

but when I run, the nested collectionView result did not appear inside the first collectionView, it just show first lblHeader from the first collectionView Cell.

How to correct my code to show nested collectionView Cell?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving height width of collection cell sizeForItemAt under UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. If it helps.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34167193)